# Devexpress Xtrareport Multicolumn mode: How to limit number of Rows per column in a subreport and display it inside another report?

Tags: c#-4.0, devexpress, subreport, multiple-columns, xtrareport

I have a subreport which contains some information about clients. I want to display that report inside another report (Suppose mainReport). For this purpose I set mainReport's Multicolumn mode to 3. My question is, can I set a number of rows to be displayed per column (For example, 20 rows per column will be displayed)? I was searching for a suitable solution but couldn't find any. Please help.

Comment: If there are greater than 60 total rows, should the report cut off further data?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention 60 rows per page.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I ended up limiting the data on the database side.

Comment: sorry, I didn't find the solution yet. Moreover the project was abandoned too.